# 2x 4 Pin CPU cable in EATX12V

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, cable, pci-express, computer-building

I have the be quiet! power 9 psu and the asus prime b450-plus motherboard I'm using a external graphics card and a NVME SDD so I guess it'll use 2 PCIe ports.

The manual says I have to plug in a 8 pin EATX +12V power plug. Now my question is: I have a 6 pin cable with a 2 pin cable, described with PCIe and 12V1, which do not fit. And I have two 4 pin cables with the description of CPU. Can I also use the two CPU cables or do I have to buy a different PSU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable your motherboard is requiring you to plug in is an 8-pin CPU/EPS ATX power, which is also called EATX12V, connector. This cable, depending on your PSU may be composed of one single 8-pin cable, or two 4-pin cables designed to be connected side by side.

You may connect the two CPU power cables into the EATX12V, and they should enter effortlessly. Do **not** force them in.

On the other hand, the other connector you are talking about is a GPU 6+2 pin power connector, which is designed to be plugged in to your dedicated GPU. **This connector is not compatible with EATX12V. Do NOT plug it in there.**

You may reference the pinout with the manuals, or the below provided picture:
[image]